# Possible to use slash (/) instead of hash (#) without page refresh window.location?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I use 'window.location.hash' to add '#something' to the URL without refreshing the page.

I want to know how to do the same but using a slash (/) instead of hash (#).

Why? I have navigation tabs and I use a jQuery and Ajax to dynamically load the data. When javascript is enabled, '#something' is added to the end of the URL to get the data. When javascript is disabled, it redirects to '/something'. So I want to fake the same URL for both.

Instead of `http://site.com/section#something` -> `http://site.com/section/something`

Thanks.

Comment: Why don'y you try  `http://site.com/section#/something/anotherthing`

Comment: No. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352343/changing-browsers-address-bar-without-refreshing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any combination *after* the hash you want, but the answer to your question is **no**, you can't do what you're asking without re-directing the user.

Being able to play with the URL without re-directing would be a security concern on some levels (can you change the domain too? why not?....see where this rabbit hole goes?).  For example changing your URL via JavaScript to say: `http://www.mybank.com` (why isn't my bank using SSL? bad bank, bad!) would be a phishers dream...so browsers don't allow messing with the URL like this at all...not without actually taking you there.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#section_4). Basically, it lets you do this:

```
history.pushState({}, 'New Title', 'new_page.html');
```

This updates the history and the location bar but *not actually load the page*. That's what you want, but it's part of HTML5, and few (if any) browsers support it at the moment. Sticking with hashes is a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

History.pushState (see the link in @Casey's post, or [Kyle Scholz' blog](http://www.kylescholz.com/blog/2010/04/html5_history_is_the_future.html)) is present in the latest versions of Safari and Firefox, and Modernizr 1.5 now tests browser support for it.  I just starting playing around with this today and it appears to do exactly what you want.

I realize this doesn't help with older browsers; some kind of window.location.hash trick will still be needed there.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you deploy [SWFAddress](http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/)?

It does get you URLs in the form of `../#/section/something` and should be pretty much what you need. It's widely used for many Flash/AJAX websites on SEO considerations.