# Change page without refresh a div into the page

Tags: javascript, partial-page-refresh

Hi i'm looking for a tutorial for understand how i can create a page with a div that isn't refreshed when the page url changes.

Ex. The facebook chat isn't refreshed when i move from an url to another.

Thanks

Comment: With the new HTML5 `history.pushState` it might no be so obvious anymore, that Ajax is used. But whenever only part the page is refreshed, it is definitely Ajax (or iframes).

Comment: @Felix +1 -- I'm guessing that's what they are doing too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX is definitely being used, although it may not seem like it because the actual URL is changing. Most AJAX apps just change the hash part of the URL (somesite.com/page/#feature1).

I don't know exactly what Facebook is doing as I haven't studied the app, but I would guess that they are using HTML5 `history.pushState()` to change the URL so that if you bookmark it or reload, it will go to the same place. I see that @Felix already mentioned this in a comment.

Take a look here for more help:

[Is there a way to change the browser's address bar without refreshing the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352343/changing-browsers-address-bar-without-refreshing/4059844#4059844)

There are lots and lots of resources on using AJAX. I personally use jQuery and find that it makes much of this quite easy.  Here's a tutorial that might help:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are wanting to use AJAX (javascripts XMLHttpRequest function). here is a great article on it along with some basic examples: [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/ajax_intro.asp)

Answer (score 0):

It's called AJAX, if you use jQuery, here's a good tutorial:

http://yensdesign.com/2008/11/creating-ajax-websites-based-on-anchor-navigation/

I wanted to post another examples if you dont use jQuery but i need more points to post more than one link, sorry...