# Browser forward/backward sliding page effect like github

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, user-experience

How can I achieve a similar effect to the browser back-button/forward button in github while browsing a repository?

To experience it try this:
https://github.com/rogerdudler/git-guide

and click on any of the html pages below: it will load smoothly (I don't know how to achieve this either) and you will be able to slide back and forth with your browser's arrows like if you were browsing in a flash applet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe they are doing this using the [History API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html)

Other related answers:

- [GitHub source dynamic navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952554/github-source-dynamic-navigation)
- [Implement github.com file seemless file navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732407/implement-github-com-file-seemless-file-navigation)

Comment: @JohnPell, yes, it appears so. When I use the network tab in Chrome's dev tools, it does appear that AJAX requests are being used to load the resources when new locations in the tree are navigated to.