# How to change the addressbar?

Tags: javascript, address-bar

I need to change the URL using Javascript, is that possible? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: I need to change firefox using Javascript, is that possible !? and how to !!

Comment: Your question and the tags together don't make sense.  Please add (much) more detail to your question, including how c# and asp.net are involved.

Comment: Based on the comment replies to BalusC's answer, this is a duplicate of [Changing browser's address bar without refreshing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352343/changing-browsers-address-bar-without-refreshing).

Answer (score 1):

You can go the way that [Google Recommends](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/learn-more.html) for making Ajax apps crawlable using the window.location.hash

Answer (score 1):

```
window.history.pushState({ page : x }, '', '/default.aspx?page=' + x);
```