# change URL link with javascript without refresh

Tags: javascript, browser-history

Is it possible to automatically change the url example.com/4000/title-2/#!4000 to example.com/4000/title-2 without to refresh the page ? Basically to remove "/#!4000" from the URL.
 Note that is important to remove the "/" before the hashbang not just the hashbang .

Comment: Automatically or programmatically?

Comment: You want to change..? The `href` of a link element, or `window.location`? I'd suggest, if you want to change the URL in the browser's address-bar, that you look at url-rewriting, with whatever you've got running on your server (Apache?).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

dont know if it is enough for you and whether it works completely cross-browser... chrome accepts:

```
location.hash = "";
```

but this keeps the "#" in the address bar

in modern browsers that completely support the html5 history api you do:

```
window.history.replaceState('Object', 'Title', '/4000/title-2');
```

EDIT: this dies not change the history of the browser

EDIT 2: just found [this stackoverflow resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352343/changing-browsers-address-bar-without-refreshing)

Comment: we need to remove # and also the "/" before it .

Comment: @mihai it is impossible without a page refresh.

Comment: [MDN entry for browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history), and [W3 entry for `replaceState()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/history.html#dom-history-replacestate). And +1 for awesome, I hadn't come across that before =)

Comment: I agree, HTML5 is offering awesome APIs :)

Comment: @TobiasKrogh is it possible to do that without to know /4000/title-2 ? I know there may be a trick to get it from window.location but I'm wondering if can be done directly using a kind  of "relative" path (e.g. "../")

Comment: checkout location.pathname (but there you might have the last "/" so you need to check and strip it on your own)... location pathname holds everything between the domain and the query respectively hash

Comment: Is there anyway to do it without changing `state`? I don't want to lose my state that is being passed from `router.navigate`

Comment: @WaleedAhmad `router.navigate` sounds like you are in an Angular context? If so you might be able to fetch the current state using `getState()` via [Location](https://angular.io/api/common/Location) and pass that to the new entry using `replaceState()`... generally speaking it might make sense to use the Angular APIs rather than native ones here but that also depends on your router settings... does this help?