# masking url that hide the target actual url in the address

Tags: javascript, php, html, url

i want to show different url in the address bar rather than actual url.

i am using this example

```js
function init() {
  document.getElementById("test").onclick = function(e) {
    jx("counter.php?url=" + escape("http://www.google.com/")); //Use your favorite ajax library here.
  }
}

window.onload = init;
```

```html
<a href="http://www.google.com/" id="test">Go To Google</a>
```

my counter.php is like this

```
<?php
  header("Location: " . $_GET['http://www.hotmail.com']);
?>
```

Comment: You can't - the address bar is the browser's code - you change it by going to a different page.

Comment: What exactly is your Problem?

Comment: In your PHP code, use `header("Location: " . $_GET['redirect_to']);`

Comment: is it possible to falsify the url to hide the target url

Comment: i want to hide my actual domain url

Comment: Aren't you already doing that? Edit: how is that supposed to work? They have to visit your site in order to see it.

Comment: No, you can't do that. Thankfully.

Comment: http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax/target_url_hiding.php i am using this example

Comment: this example shows we can hide our target url

Comment: What is the problem that you are having with the code that you have posted?

Comment: i wanted to go to hotmail website but url will be showing  google

Comment: this code take to google page with same google url]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change URL link with javascript without refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261393/change-url-link-with-javascript-without-refresh)

Comment: Why would you ever want to do this? Are you trying to fool the user? What would be the purpose of that, other than some kind of fraud attempt? Showing the user a different URL than the one being displayed in the bar is an abuse of the trust between the user and the site they are visiting. Thankfully it's not really possible to do this.

Comment: hold your far fetched assumption to your self. some site needs security.

Comment: @Sarah_Salar — Lying about your URL doesn't provide security.

Comment: it is not lying if u do not understand my problem then kindly be quite.

Comment: If your reason is  not malicious, then to me this sounds like some attempt at "security by obscurity"...which as is well known, is not really security at all. Can you kindly explain exactly why you want to do this? What kind of security are you trying to achieve? What problem are you trying to guard against? If we can understand your motivation, then we might be able to tell you a sensible way to achieve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to show different url in the address bar rather than actual url.

In general: You can't.

---

[The History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) allows you to manipulate the history to show different URLs without changing page … but only within the same origin. (So you could be on `http://example.com/` but show `http://example.com/other` but not `http://example.net/`).

This is intended so that heavily Ajaxy websites can have real URLs for different "pages" while generating the pages client-side. The intention is that the same pages can be generated server-side when the URL is visited directly or by a client which doesn't support JavaScript. This allows for search engine friendly, accessible content, with a performance boost while navigating from page to page within the site when the client allows it.

---

It is possible for one URL to serve the same content as another URL. This could be a simple static copy, or it could be pulled dynamically with server-side code (or Ajax if [the CORS policy allows it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-xxx-no-access-control-allow-origin-header/35553666#35553666)).

Of course, all relative URLs would need to be updated when the content is copied otherwise they will just break.

Naturally, you couldn't use this to make `http://www.google.com/` display the same content as `http://www.hotmail.com`: You don't control `http://www.google.com` so cannot change the content it serves.

Comment: i am using google.com and hotmail.com as an example