# How do links work in soundcloud?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have noticed in quite few websites like soundcloud where when you click on a link, the page loads like it was there only something like ajax, but still the address changes in address bar.

For example, when I am exploring sounds on soundcloud, clicking on a link, opens the page but the background music keeps on playing. If its ajax, then how do the address changes in address bar.

I am newbie web developer, want to learn this technique!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, you should have a look at this http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Answer (score 1):

Check out [history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).

HTML5-friendly browsers supports new history apis named pushState/replaceState that enables javascript to take control of browser history without reload the page. In older browser, features like location.hash is usually used.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this question's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4059844/1558255

In it you can see examples for the use of `window.history` in HTML5 such as the following from Alfred Nerstu's answer.

> ```
>   window.history.pushState('Object', 'Title', '/new-url');
> ```
>
> If you just want to change the url without being able to go back
>
> ```
>   window.history.replaceState('Object', 'Title', '/another-new-url');
> ```
>
> The object can be used for ajax navigation:
>
> ```
>   window.history.pushState({ id: 35 }, 'Viewing item #35', '/item/35');
>
>   window.onpopstate = function (e) {
>      var id = e.state.id;
>      load_item(id);
>   };
> ```