# Make content on (example) domain.com/file seem like is hosted in domain.com or other domain

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess

```
<script>
document.write(location.href);
</script>
```

gives me the domain with the directory which is for example (something.com/g) what i want is that content hosted on something.com/g seems like is hosted in something.com so that it tells all eveything im hosted in something.com.if you could give the response in javascript it would help.thank you

Comment: For hopefully very obvious reasons, you can't (unless you change the DNS on the user's machine which needs their involvement and is not trivial)

Comment: Talk about shady practice.

Comment: So, a possible effort to salvage the question: "www.something.com" is the domain. If the browser's URL is "www.something.com/subfolder/place.php", the domain is still "www.something.com", and the query directory (probably has many names) is "/subfolder/place.php". If you are simply trying to have a browser at "something.com/viewContacts", while taking information from "something.com/phplib/datastructs/contacts.php" (a PHP file in that directory), that's much more doable - but the question sounds very different from that as it is.

Comment: <script>

document.write(location.href);

</script>
 gives me the domain with the directory which a (something.com/g) what i want is that content hosted on something.com/g seems like is hosted in something.com

Answer (score 1):

It's not ever wise to try to fake a browser into thinking they are at a different domain. I personally don't know how to do it nor will I ever try. This is explicitly unethical.

However, on a more constructive note, you might find part of your answer here: [Is there a way to change the browser's address bar without refreshing the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352343/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-browsers-address-bar-without-refreshing-the-page)

Answer (score 0):

1. Point (using DNS) the domain you want the content to appear on at a web server
2. Host the files you want to be available on that domain on that server
3. Configure the server the original domain is pointing to to issue a 301 or 302 redirect response when the directory is accessed

Comment: both the domain.com and domain.com/file are in the same server i am looking for a javascript