# Onclick change url using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, onclick

I am trying to change a url using jquery.

So once the button is clicked it will change the parent url but it will not redirect.

For example, If the url is,

http://www.xyz.com then it will become http://www.xyz.com/abc but will not be redirected.

My Code:

```
$('.clickme').click(function () {
    window.location.hash = 'xyz';
});
```

Is it at all possible?

Please suggest.

JSfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/Tn8BW/3/

Comment: Yes it is possible. Show us your code so far and we will see where you went wrong. Also do you mean the URL on the anchor tag or the URL in the address bar?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352343/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-browsers-address-bar-without-refreshing-the-page

Comment: are you using window.location?

Comment: @Huan The fiddle is added.

Comment: Maess no it should not redirect.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FGuide%2FDOM%2FManipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/Tn8BW/4/show/

Comment: Thanks Aamir. It works. Just one thing is it good with seo?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Javascript can luckilly modify browser's history, and change the url. This example will add new row to your browser's history, and you are able to use back button to go to that page.

HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.xyz.com/abc" id="link">abc</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#link').click(function() {
   window.history.pushState('obj', 'newtitle', '/abc');
   return false;
});
```

Or if you want to use url hashes(like in your code):

```
$('#link').click(function () {
    window.location.hash = 'xyz';
    return false;
});
```

That will not redirect, it stays on the page.

Comment: Thanks @aksu. In first example is it supported by all browsers/versions?

Comment: It's supported pretty generally, even in some of the mobile browsers! you can check more on http://caniuse.com/#feat=history.

Comment: Search engines ingnore hashtags, so they will not indexed. You can read more on that blog http://www.phoenixrealm.com/the-power-of-the-hash-in-seo/

Comment: Thanks @aksu. One last question. Is there any way to remove the added hashtag then.

Comment: Well you can use my first example. That doesn't create hashtags.

Comment: I would downvote, but my reputation is to low... never ever use "return false" for this.What you want to do is "event.preventDefault()"!

Comment: I am curious myself too. 
Is there any reason why you used `return false` instead of `event.preventDefault()`?

Comment: It's easier to remember.

Comment: Perfect! Just what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

instead of window.location you need to modify the history

example code

```
var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
```