# Update the url using javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to update my page URL on click of something. 
Then when I share the updated URL I want it to open in that same updated state so that I can share the updated view. How do I achieve this??

Comment: This should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475504/onclick-change-url-using-jquery

Comment: Hey thank you, I will try to implement that.