# .htaccess & PHP — Allow // in GET data

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**If you're going to -1 this question, tell me how I can improve it, rather than just leaving it.**

*This is a dup with a few edits*

I'm making an open-source piece of software, but my .htaccess needs a little tuning.

How do I allow a URL such as `www.mydomain.net/forum/method/user//abc` and keep the `//` when grabbing it in my PHP code?

I've looked here: [allow slash in url .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20686284/allow-slash-in-url-htaccess)

But that was no help.

Here's what I have:

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/=$1 [NC,QSA,L,NE]
```

And:

**geturl.php**

```
$url = (isset($_GET['/']) ? $_GET['/'] : null);
die($url);
```

Output: `account/signup/2/sskssks`

URL: `account/signup/2//sskssks`

Expected output: `account/signup/2//sskssks`

Basically, something is removing/trimming the // and setting it to /.

Comment: I think empty parts in URLs are resolved leaving just one `/`. Why do you need `//`?

Comment: Do you have any other RewriteRule in this .htaccess? What happens if you omit `NE` from the rewrite flags?

Comment: `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` or e.g. `REDIRECT_URL` will retain the original and unnormalized path. To avert downvotes, try not to repost without further research.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski nothing.

Comment: Right - it's preserved in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` if you just rewrite all requests to index.php with no params (except requests to index.php)

Comment: @mario I reposted with a better explanation.

Comment: Guys, is there a way I could remove all *directories* from $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] in php and get the rest? This would be awesome.

Answer (score 2):

[Section 3 of RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3) covers the generic syntax of *path components* in a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI).

```
  path          = path-abempty    ; begins with "/" or is empty
                / path-absolute   ; begins with "/" but not "//"
                / path-noscheme   ; begins with a non-colon segment
                / path-rootless   ; begins with a segment
                / path-empty      ; zero characters

  path-abempty  = *( "/" segment )
  path-absolute = "/" [ segment-nz *( "/" segment ) ]
  path-noscheme = segment-nz-nc *( "/" segment )
  path-rootless = segment-nz *( "/" segment )
  path-empty    = 0<pchar>
  segment       = *pchar
  segment-nz    = 1*pchar
  segment-nz-nc = 1*( unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / "@" )
                ; non-zero-length segment without any colon ":"

  pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
```

The line defining `segment-nz` indicates that individual segments in a path, i.e. `/aaa/bbb/ccc` ('aaa', 'bbb', and 'ccc' are each segments), cannot be empty.  They must contain at least one(1) `pchar`.  There are special cases for beginning an absolute path that is rooted and empty (`/`) and simply empty, and a couple others that are rarely encountered when discussing Web URLs.

Your URI path is being *normalized*, stripping the extra `/` from your path.  If that slash is important, you will need to send it as *data* by using [percent encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1).

Comment: I'm not good at htaccess, so what modifications would I need?