# Convert Wordpress Query String to Path

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm building a site with multiple versions of the same page. 
So if the user goes to example.com/?u=user1, they get a custom branded version of the home page using JS which determines the query string and matches that to an image.

My question is how can I get the user to be able to visit example.com/user1 or example.com/start/user1 rather than the query string URL? Is there any way to do this?

I've tried rewrites but it isn't working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^start/([^/]+)/?$ /?u=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/start [NC]
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

I believe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352343/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-browsers-address-bar-without-refreshing-the-page) addresses that question and has the code you'll need. I don't think it's necessary to do this with .htaccess. It would be much easier with JS.

Comment: Thanks, but I want users to also be able to access the page through that path